# How to boot Ubuntu Cloud image using QEMU

Tags: qemu, disk-image

I created config files

```
echo 'password: asd' > userdata
echo 'local-hostname: localhost' > metadata
```

Then created iso from them

```
genisoimage -output geniso.iso -volid cidata -joliet -rock userdata metadata
```

And created QEMU image

```
virt-install --connect qemu:///system virt-type qemu --name mymachine --memory 4096 --vcpus=2 --os-type linux --os-variant ubuntu18.04 --disk path=ubuntu-18.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.img,format=qcow2 --disk  geniso.iso,device=cdrom --import --network network=default --noautoconsole
```

Screenschot below shows that machine has been changed to `localhost` but the password did not work.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [cloud-init config format](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html) is a bit more structured than what you used.
And the minimal change to your case is to recognize that the leading `#cloud-init` isn't optional.

Your question is pretty close to [this](https://www.theurbanpenguin.com/using-cloud-images-in-kvm/) or [this](https://medium.com/@art.vasilyev/use-ubuntu-cloud-image-with-kvm-1f28c19f82f8) example, so I recommend to get your remaining details there as needed.